# How do I query a user by UserId in MongoDB using User management methods and pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to query a created user by its UUID id. I don't want to make a collection that holds users since there's already user management methods to make use of. db.getUser() only takes `username` as a parameter. Why can I not query by unique id?

I'm using pymongo and I have two options at the moment, either create a separate user table and then query that table with a unique uuid using something like `.find()` or I could use pymongo by using `pymongo.MongoClient['db'].command("usersInfo)` and filter on the returned users? Is there a more efficient way to do this? Something I'm missing in the docs?

Comment: Driver user management functionality is for database users, not for application users.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm making use of it on the backend though, no application user is making use of it. Guessing what I'm trying is an anti-pattern.

Comment: If you used the database users as your application users I can sort of understand what you are doing, although I still wouldn't recommend it, but the impression I got was you do have separate application users in which case database user management functionality simply does not apply.